# Centering divs on top of an image

Tags: css, html, centering

For some reason, I can't get this to work:
[Website](http://www.wearereign.com)

(The red and green boxes will be removed once they're properly positioned.)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to achieve? To me its not clear

Comment: Sorry, I figured it would be obvious. The red box I'm trying to center over the "Dark Omen (Swtor) Enter here" and the green box over the "Reign (Tera) Enter here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the following properties along with position

top:0;
left:0;

you can also set top or left property in order to make the boxes visible at the center

and if you want that your boxes will remain inside the center div then make the div with id splash to position: relative

it will help in solving your issue

Comment: Thanks! This was the most simple solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The overall concept of centering something in css is quite simple. First you need a relative positioned container. The child element to be centered must have a fixed width and height and be absolute positioned at 50% from the top and 50% from the left, and both top and left margins must be negative half of the width and height respectively. In other words:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="" alt=""/>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

.

```
#container { position: relative; }
img { dispaly: block; } /* It fills the container */
#box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; /* Fixed */
    height 150px; /* Fixed */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -75px; /* 300/2 */
    margin-left: -150px; /* 150/2 */
}
```

Comment: As long as you know the height of the item which needs centered, negative margins are all you need. Things do get trickier if you don't know the height.

Comment: Yeah, in those cases, I usually just use a simple jquery plugin http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/RMsSh/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you can do this with CSS positioning tho for what you appear to be trying to do, you might be better off using an image map

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

This allows you to set certain regions of an image as a link.